# writing an awk command to print every line that has at least one field

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

How can I write an awk command that prints only lines with at least one field

```
awk '{if (NF>0) print }'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You command works, and prints lines with one or more fields. But `awk` prints by default, so you can simplify it:

```
awk 'NF > 0' file.txt
```